# List custom class members and type

Tags: c#

This seems like the most basic thing ever but somehow I couldnt find the answer and couldnt figure it out.

Lets say I have a custom class:

```
public class WineCellar
{
   public string year;
   public string wine;
   public double nrbottles;
}
```

Now I would like a function:

```
WineCellar ex = new WineCellar();
ex.members();
```

This should return: year, wine, nrbootles.

And:

```
 ex.members().types();
```

Should return: string, string, double

I guess on the same note, lets say you have one instance {2010, Rioja, 6}. Is there syntax that returns these by indexing? i.e.

```
ex[1]
```

or

```
ex.{1}
```

that returns 2010?

Sorry for the basic question.

Comment: well, if I do ex.gettype() it returns winecellar, but that is not what I want. Nothing else seems to fit

Comment: Point of interest, arrays are zero-indexed, so `ex[1]` would return the value of `wine`, not `year`. With regards to the actual question, is there a particular reason you _want_ to do this? If you're trying to use it to solve a bigger problem, there's almost definitely an easier and better way to go about it.

Comment: Agreed with @Michelle. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: fair enough. The bigger thing is that I want to only adjust my code in one place if I need to add a new feature. Currently I have to do it in the class and then again when I do an INSERT INTO with OleDB into a DB because I cannot figure out how to index the column names for the table. What I would like is create the table in Access and paste a mirror of List<WineCellar>. Does that make sense?

Comment: @nik Then you should ask that question instead. Open a new question and write up a full question asking how to do that.

Comment: To keep changes localized, you could maintain a static `Dictionary` in `WineCellar` of the column names and types. You still need to keep it manually updated, but it's in the same place as the rest of the changes you'll be making and avoids unnecessary work trying to figure it out dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Michelle said in the comments, this sounds like a wrong approach to a bigger problem.

However, if you do need this kind of things, you can get the using reflection:

```
//returns a list of propertyInfo objects for the class 
// with all kinds of usefull information
public List<PropertyInfo> GetMemberInfos()
{
    return this.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();
}

//returns a list of property names
public List<string> GetMemberNames
{
    return this.GetType().GetProperties().Select(pi => pi.Name).ToList();
}

//returns a list of names of the property types
public List<string> GetMemberTypeNames
{
    return this.GetType().GetProperties().Select(pi => pi.PropertyType.Name).ToList();
}

//indexer that uses the property name to get the value
//since you are mixing types, you can't get more specific than object
public object this[string property]
{
  get { return this.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(this); }
  set { this.GetType().GetProperty(property).SetValue(this, value); }
}

//indexer that uses the property index in the properties array to get the value
public object this[int index]
{
  get { return this.GetType().GetProperties()[index].GetValue(this); }
  set { this.GetType().GetProperties()[index].SetValue(this, value); }
}
```

Note that all of these methods are very slow, because in general, reflection is slow. You can try to cache some thing to speed it up.

Also, the last method is ***downright dangerous***. It will (try to) read and write to an array that does not have a guaranteed order. In fact, the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx) specifies:

> The GetProperties method does not return properties in a particular
>   order, such as alphabetical or declaration order. Your code must not
>   depend on the order in which properties are returned, because that
>   order varies.

For example, if you change your class to:

```
public class WineCellar
{
  public string year;
  public string region;
  public string wine;
  public double nrbottles;
}
```

and you were used to using `winecellar[1] = "Pinot Noir"` that will most likely now update the `region` property, instead of the `wine` property.

Comment: +1 Small note, in this case it should be `GetFields` instead of `GetProperties`.  (Though that again casts a light on how fragile OP's desired approach is).

Comment: @DaxFohl I've completely missed that these are in fact public fields (oh, the horror).

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I get it now. This is a very bad approach. Maybe it is better to leave it undynamic. Bigger question posted here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235414/dynamically-adjust-create-table-and-insert-into-statement-based-on-custom-class) - if you have suggestions it would be very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would implement Members method (In case if you wanted property names as strings)

```
public List<string> Members()
{
   List<string> propNames = new List<string>();
   foreach (var prop in typeof(WineCellar).GetProperties())
   {
       propNames.Add(prop.Name);
   }
   return propNames;
}
```

And this is how you would implement Types (In same case)

```
public List<string> Types()
{
   List<string> propTypes = new List<string>();
   foreach (var prop in typeof(WineCellar).GetProperties())
   {
       propTypes.Add(prop.PropertyType.ToString());
   }
   return propTypes ;
}
```

And the last thing if you want to get values of the parameters like this ex[n] you can just make a simple indexer in you class like this

```
public string this[int n]
{
   get
   {
       int current = 0;
       foreach (var prop in typeof(WineCellar).GetProperties())
       {
          if (current == n)
             return prop.GetValue(this, null).ToString();
          current++;
       }
       return null;
   }
}
```

but for these methods to work you should change your variables into properties like this

```
public class WineCellar
{
   public string Year { get; set; }
   public string Wine { get; set; }
   public double Nrbottles { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection

```
foreach (var prop in typeof(WineCellar).GetProperties())
            {

                if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(double) || prop.PropertyType == typeof(double?))
                {

                }
            }
```

to get the value, you can do:

```
prop.GetValue(obj);
```